# Create table for a protocol in latex

Tags: tables

I have to achieve the following:
[image]

I can achieve about

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c c c|c }
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & t \\ 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & t \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 & t \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 & t \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

However this does not really give the clear effect that I wanted!
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: The link between the two images is not very clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The rotated text at the right margins?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}C{3cm}C{3cm}|c}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Large User 1} & \Large User 2 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Large User 3} & \\\cline{1-3}
  \strut &&&\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{Phase1}}\\
  \strut &&&\\
  Operation1 & Operation1 &&\\\cline{1-3}
  \strut Operation1 && Operation1 &\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{Phase2}}\\
  \strut &&&\\
  \strut & Operation1 &&\\\cline{1-3}
  \strut & Operation1 &&\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{Phase3}}\\
  \strut && Operation1 &\\
  Operation1 & Operation1 &&\\\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]